# what are the factors which determine if the environment need to have a dataverse data source or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, solution, dataverse

We want to create a production Environment, for now, the environment will contain those main components:-

1. Solutions
2. Connection to SharePoint
3. Power App
4. Power automate
5. Environment variables
6. we need certain users to be able to create Power App, Power Automate & Connection to SharePoint
7. we need certain users to ONLY be defined inside the Run-Only for certain instant Power Automate flows

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzeY2.png)

so do we need to have a data verse data source for our environment when creating it? or we are fine without it at this stage?

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to have a development/test environment for testing something like flows, forms, custom add-ins and etc. before they are published to the real production environment.